# Customize default order of attributes within @Page directive

Tags: asp.net, webforms, master-pages, meta-tags

This is mostly me being OCD but also serves a practical purpose of helping remind me to always put a meta description tag on each page.  I've set up my master page to use the `Page.MetaDescription` and `Page.MetaKeywords` like this:

```
<title><%: Page.Title %></title>
<meta name="description" content="<%: Page.MetaDescription %>" />
<meta name="keywords" content="<%: Page.MetaKeywords %>" />
```

And by default, new child pages have this as the first line:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPages/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="Namespace.WebForm1" %>
```

As you can see, only `Title=""` automatically gets added and I would like for `MetaDescription=""` and `MetaKeywords=""` to be included as well whenever I add a new child page.  Even better, I'd like it to be formatted to be more human-readable like this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPages/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="Namespace.WebForm1" 
  Title="" 
  MetaDescription="" 
  MetaKeywords="" 
  %>
```

Is there any way to accomplish this?  I'd like to avoid anything that requires setting these values in the codebehind so quick updates can be made without recompilation (i.e. simply change the .aspx file).